# Name for long chain of double-bonded carbon atoms

Tags: carbon-allotropes

Long ago (over 10 years), I read an article in my father's copy of Chemistry World on a substance consisting of many carbon atoms in a chain double bonded to each other:

$$\ldots\ce{=C=C=C=C=C=}\ldots$$

So, no other elements; a very exotic allotrope of carbon.  As I remember, the article was sceptical of the claims of synthesizing this compound but its existence is not my question.  My question is much more basic: what is the name of this hypothetical compound?  I cannot remember and I have failed to find it in searches (possibly due to my searching skills).

Comment: Cumulenes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulene

Comment: That's close though this (hypothetical) substance had much longer chains.  A sort of 1D analogue of graphene.

Comment: @orthocresol can it be called an allene system?

Comment: @Vega No. Allenes have $n = 2$ and other things on the end.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_acetylenic_carbon

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cplett.2004.01.007

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks, that's it.  If you convert your comment to an answer, I would accept it.